# Selenium Maven Plugin - Selenese goal missing firefox profile parameter

Tags: maven, selenium

right I have hit a wall using the Selenium Maven Plugin - using the selenese goal which is all swell - however when it comes to executing the tests in firefox, the plugin launches a fresh firefox profile, which doesn't have the company proxy configured.

Now if i were simply executing my html suite directly with the selenium server jar I could specify a firefox profile - however it appears to be the case this has not been included in as a parameter in the selenese goal for this plugin. madness!

there are such parameters for the start-server goal, so why not selenese?

Has anybody else faced this issue? Any workarounds?

Appreciate all sensible input.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would post my solution should anyone else come accross this...

Simply need to get the selenium maven plugin source, and patch it. The constants are available in the selenium server RemoteControlConfiguration class however this plugin doesn't make use of them all in the SeleneseMojo. So it is a very simple fix:

Set the properties that we want to change when the seleneseMojo starts the selenium server. So in this case I wanted to make use of `firefoxProfileTemplate` so I did this:

```
 def conf = new RemoteControlConfiguration()
 conf.port = port
 conf.singleWindow = !multiWindow
 conf.firefoxProfileTemplate = firefoxProfileTemplate

 def server = new SeleniumServer(slowResources, conf)
 server.start()
```

Now I can specify a firefoxProfileTemplate value in my maven project execution configurations and therefore specify a firefox profile when running selenium html suites through maven.